# How to customize express.js url query parameter parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So, [req.query](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) returns the hash of the query parameters. Even better, if a parameter is actually a json object, then it parses it into the respective json, which is awesome.

However, how can I customize this parsing? For instance, I would like a certain value to be parsed as a number, rather than as a string. Surely, I can do it post factum and modify the returned object. But, I am interesting to know whether the process can be customized in general.

**EDIT**

For example, consider the following request:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/admin/api/inventory?rowsPerPage=25&page=0&q%5Bqty%5D%5B%24lt%5D=100
```

Decoding it we get:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/admin/api/inventory?rowsPerPage=25&page=0&q[qty][$lt]=100
```

Now, express converts these query parameters to

```
req.query = {rowsPerPage: "25", page: "0", q: {qty: {$lt: "100"}}
```

My problem is with "25", "0" and "100" - I want them to be numbers. So, I can either change the `req.query` post factum or interfere with the parsing process. I want to learn the latter.

Answer (score 0):

the query string is parsed here [connect-query.js](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/query.js) which is based on tj's querystring parser [node-querystring](http://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring) you may want to look into that or into nodes querystring parser. AFAIK u cannot change the qs parsing without forking express and changing something in there. anyways handling this cases in a middleware or later on in your app where you need the strings to be numbers would be better performance wise instead of checking for numbers in every request.

Comment: I am not talking about the body. The question is about the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [req.query](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/query.html) middleware provided by [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/). It is based on [node-querystring](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it (using CoffeeScript and Lodash):

```
app.use (req, res, next) ->
  # Ensure all integer parameters are parsed correctly.
  _.each req.query, (value, key) ->
    unless isNaN value
      req.query[key] = _.parseInt value
  next()
```

The same can easily be achieved with JavaScript and no extensions.